# Asp.Net Membership Provider - how to get user by email address within a domain?

Tags: asp.net, membership-provider

When using the ASP.NET Membership Provider is there any way to get a user by email address within a specific domain?  I know that there is `System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUserNameByEmail(emailAddress)` but I am hoping that there is some way to restrict the search to a specific user domain.

Answer (score 0):

See:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.activedirectorymembershipprovider.getusernamebyemail(v=vs.110).aspx

> The provider uses a subtree search starting at the search point
>   specified in the connection string.

If you want to limit the search, I would configure the provider connection string to point at that specific domain & OU you want to search within.

Example:

```
<add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://example.com/DC=example,DC=com/OU=Accounts"  />
```